# QMessageBox .gif file is not visible

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox, qeventloop

I have a `QMessageBox` and I put an animated gif on this Dialog with `QLabel` and inside `QMovie` instead of an icon. But there is a problem with the gif. When I refresh the screen somehow `QMessageBox` is working but the gif is not visible anymore.

```
QMessageBox msgBox(this);       
msgBox.setWindowTitle("Warning");
msgBox.setText("      This element is UNDER CONSTRUCTION!");
QLabel* label = new QLabel(&msgBox);                
label-> setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
QPixmap p("Resources/Images/General/construct.gif");

label->setPixmap(p);
label->setFixedHeight(40);
label->setFixedWidth(45);

QMovie *movie = new QMovie("Resources/Images/General/construct.gif");
label->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();    

label->show();

QAbstractButton *myYesButton = msgBox.addButton("I accept risk!", QMessageBox::YesRole);
QAbstractButton *myNoButton  = msgBox.addButton("Cancel", QMessageBox::NoRole);         
msgBox.exec();

if(msgBox.clickedButton() == myNoButton) return;
```

Comment: What I encountered a few times, regarding placing elements/QFrames in other elements: when I forget to set it's geometry, the element is drawn, but not visible. Maybe its the case here? Try setting an x and y cordinate or simply use ::setGeometry( qRect, qPoint) (not sure if thats exactly the parameters, please validate)